# Cелектор JQuery (по тексту)

Tags: jquery

Например, имеется строка `<h1>Слово1 Слово2 Слово3</h1>`.

`$('h1:contains("Слово3")').text()` выдаст всю строку целиком, а необходимо выбирать только определенное слово/текст/часть текста. Существует какой-нибудь фильтр или как по другому можно это сделать?

Comment: Пример бы что именно вы хотите получить, так сложно представить что именно нужно.

Comment: Строка <h1>Кабинет №15</h1>. Из нее нужно получить только "15".

Comment: А поиск планируете по слову Кабинет?

Comment: По первому появлению на странице "15". Там получается это уникальное число. Просто не знаю пока как по другому.

Comment: Скорее всего тут проблема XY и ТС решает какую-то задачу, как он думает ему надо решать. Лучше, скорее, узнать в целом что решается и для чего это нужно и возможно тогда бы нашлось решение

Comment: С первым помогли разобраться, спасибо. Обновил вопрос, появился еще один момент.

Comment: @NikitaBorisov нет, так не делается. один вопрос - один ответ. если есть другой - задавай его уже в другом треде

Comment: Впервые тут. Хорошо,спасибо за информацию!

Comment: @NikitaBorisov `С первым помогли разобраться` - а кто и где? в ответе?  или...?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В ответе programmer403 и Yaroslav Molchan про проверку на странице.

Answer (score 1):

После прочтения комментария вот пример как найти ваши '15':

```js
var search_str = "15";
var search_str_length = search_str.length;

if ($("h1:contains('"+search_str+"')")) {
  
  var s_str_index = $("h1").text().indexOf(search_str);

  var get_text = $("h1").text().substr(s_str_index, search_str_length);
  console.log(get_text);
  
  var text = $("h1").text();
  var re = new RegExp(get_text,"g");
  
  text = text.replace(re, "<span style='background:yellow'>"+get_text+"</span>");
  $("h1").html(text);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Многабукав тут там -15 15  = Ка15бинет №15</h1>
```

Можно так

```js
if ($('h1:contains("разделен")')) {

  var a = $('h1').text().split(' ');


  jQuery.map(a, function(value, key) {
    if (value.indexOf('разделен') == 0) {
      $(".str").append("<span style='background:yellow'>"+value+"</span> ");
    } else {
      $(".str").append(" "+value+" ");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Слова разделены пробелом</h1>

<div class='str'></div>
```